# Polly to change query string on retry

Tags: c#, .net-core, query-string, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm using .NET 5 and want to use Polly to change the query string of a request on a retry.
Background - I have a fixed quota of requests per minute which is allowed from my IP address. If I exceed the limit, I get a specific 4xx status code. In this case I want to add a query string argument `?key=xxx` to handle peaks. The requests counting towards the API key are more expensive and should only apply if reached the quota temporary.

I use the named client many times in different places.

Is this a scenario for which Polly is suitable? Or from a design perspective, is handling this in business logic the clean way? Then I need to wrap this logic to avoid repeating myself.

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://test.com");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == 4xx)
  response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://test.com?key=XXX")

// continue with regular workflow - handling errors or process response
```

Comment: I don't think Polly is suited for that kind of policy. You may be able to write your own hander, possibly even using Polly in the handler, but I'm not sure it's really worth using Polly here.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetStringAsync` returns a `Task<string>` so you can't examine the reponse's `StatusCode`.
So, you need to use `GetAsync` which returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

Because the request uri is the only thing which is changing between the calls that's why you need to receive that as a parameter:

```cs
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); //or use IHttpClientFactory
static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PerformRequest(string uri)
{
    Console.WriteLine(uri);
    return await client.GetAsync(uri);
}
```

In order to have a parameter-less action which can be performed by the retry policy we need an address iterator and a wrapper around the `PerformRequest`:

```cs
static IEnumerable<string> GetAddresses()
{
    yield return "https://test.com";
    yield return "https://test.com?key=XXX";
    ...
}
```

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerator<string> UrlIterator = GetAddresses().GetEnumerator();
static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest()
{
    if (UrlIterator.MoveNext())
        return await PerformRequest(UrlIterator.Current);
    return null;
}
```

Each time when you call the `GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest` it retrieves the next fallback url and then executes the request against that.

What's left is the retry policy itself:

```cs
var retryPolicyForNotSuccessAnd4xx = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => response != null && !response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .OrResult(response => response != null && (int)response.StatusCode > 400 && (int)response.StatusCode < 500)
    .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

- If the `GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest` returns `null` because we have run out of fallback urls then we exit from the retry
- If the statusCode is between 200 and 299 then we exit from the retry
- If the statusCode is between 300 and 400 or greater than 500 then we exit from the retry
- In every other case we perform a retry

The usage could look like this:

```cs
var response = await retryPolicyForNotSuccessAnd4xx.ExecuteAsync(async () => await GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest());
if (response == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All requests failed");
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
    
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full source code:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var retryPolicyForNotSuccessAnd4xx = Policy
            .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => response != null && !response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            .OrResult(response => response != null && (int)response.StatusCode > 400 && (int)response.StatusCode < 500)
            .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        var response = await retryPolicyForNotSuccessAnd4xx.ExecuteAsync(async () => await GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest());
        if (response == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All requests failed");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetAddresses()
    {
        yield return "https://test.com";
        yield return "https://test.com?key=XXX";
    }

    private static readonly IEnumerator<string> UrlIterator = GetAddresses().GetEnumerator();
    
    static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetNewAddressAndPerformRequest()
        => UrlIterator.MoveNext() ? await PerformRequest(UrlIterator.Current) : null;
    
    static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PerformRequest(string uri)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uri);
        return await client.GetAsync(uri);
    }
}
```